# Oracle PL/SQL select and update

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I keep getting the "no data found" when I execute this PL/SQL block. If I comment out the output line, everything outputs as I would suspect, but the update statement never executes. Any ideas?

```
set serveroutput on;
Declare
   TYPE type_emp IS RECORD(
        emp_salary emp.salary%TYPE);
     rec_emp type_emp;
   v_stars varchar2(50) ;
   v_count number(3);
   s_num number(3);
begin
 SELECT min(employee_id) into s_num from emp;
 SELECT count(*) into v_count from emp;
 v_count := v_count + s_num;
 for i in s_num .. v_count loop
   SELECT salary
     into rec_emp
     from emp
    where employee_id = i; 
    if rec_emp.emp_salary <1000 then 
        v_stars := null;
      elsif rec_emp.emp_salary >=1000 and rec_emp.emp_salary <2000 then 
        v_stars := '*';
      elsif rec_emp.emp_salary >=2000 and rec_emp.emp_salary <3000 then 
        v_stars := '**';
      elsif rec_emp.emp_salary >=3000 and rec_emp.emp_salary <4000 then 
        v_stars := '***';
      elsif rec_emp.emp_salary >=4000 and rec_emp.emp_salary <5000 then 
        v_stars := '****';
      elsif rec_emp.emp_salary >=5000 and rec_emp.emp_salary <6000 then 
        v_stars := '*****';
      elsif rec_emp.emp_salary >=6000 and rec_emp.emp_salary <7000 then 
        v_stars := '******';
      elsif rec_emp.emp_salary >=7000 and rec_emp.emp_salary <8000 then 
        v_stars := '*******';
      elsif rec_emp.emp_salary >=8000 and rec_emp.emp_salary <9000 then
        v_stars := '********';
      elsif rec_emp.emp_salary >=9000 and rec_emp.emp_salary <10000 then 
        v_stars := '*********';
      elsif rec_emp.emp_salary >=10000 and rec_emp.emp_salary <11000 then 
        v_stars := '**********';
      elsif rec_emp.emp_salary >=11000 and rec_emp.emp_salary <12000 then 
        v_stars := '***********';
      elsif rec_emp.emp_salary >=12000  then 
        v_stars := '************';
    end if;
    --dbms_output.put_line(rec_emp.emp_salary || '   ' || i || '      '|| v_stars);  
    update emp set emp.stars = v_stars where employee_id = i;
 end loop;
 end;
```

Comment: In addition to Jeffrey's answer you could simplify all the `elsif` statements to something like: `if rec_emp.emp_salary <1000 then v_stars := null; else v_stars := lpad('*',least(floor(rec_emp.emp_salary/1000),12),'*'); end if;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using a very unusual method to iterate through all the records in the table. Your method assumes that the employee IDs are contiguous (i.e. no gaps). It also has an off-by-one error.

Let's say your table has the following rows:

```
100
101
102
103
104
```

Firstly you get the minimum employee ID: `s_num = 100`.

Then, you get the count of records: `v_count = 5`.

Finally, you add these together to get the upper bound: `s_num + v_count = 105`

Can you see the problem with your loop now? On the last iteration, your query:

```
SELECT salary
 into rec_emp
 from emp
where employee_id = i;
```

Will look for employee ID 105, which raises `NO_DATA_FOUND`. The DBMS_OUTPUT calls were already done, so you'd see the output; but the unhandled exception causes a rollback, which means your UPDATEs are undone.

Instead, you could make your loop much simpler, e.g.:

```
FOR rec_emp IN (SELECT employee_id, salary AS emp_salary FROM emp) LOOP
  if rec_emp.emp_salary <1000 then 
    v_stars := null;
  elsif <snip>
    ...
  end if;
  --dbms_output.put_line(rec_emp.emp_salary || '   ' || i || '      '|| v_stars);  
  update emp set emp.stars = v_stars where employee_id = i;
END LOOP;
```

The above code is slightly more efficient too. It could be made even more efficient, but I don't want this answer to go too far past what you've got so far.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you good explanation. I ended up changing the select statement that gets the upperbound to SELECT MAX(employee_id) into v_count from emp;

Answer (score 1):

@Jeffrey Kemp's answer is entirely correct.  Additionally, you could simplify this down to a single statement (as hinted at by @John Doyle's comment):

```
UPDATE emp
SET    emp.stars   =
          CASE WHEN rec_emp.emp_salary < 1000 
          THEN NULL 
          ELSE LPAD('*', LEAST(FLOOR(rec_emp.emp_salary / 1000), 12), '*') END
```